# Iterator which asynchronously fetches the next batch from a service [kotlin coroutines]

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, google-cloud-platform, iterator, java-stream

I've implemented a synchronous iterator which fetches batches of data from an external service (may take some time or hang).

I'd like to fetch a next batch asynchronously while the caller code iterates through the entries of a sequence of the current batch.

Ideally, I'd like to use **kotlin coroutines**.

Desired process:

1. The iterator fetches the 1st batch
2. The iterator starts fetching 2nd batch in the background
3. Meanwhile, the caller processes the first batch
4. After processing the first batch, the caller can immediately process the 2nd batch which was was fetched by the iterator in the background
5. The iterator starts fetching the 3rd batch in the background
6. After processing the 2nd batch, the caller can  immediately process the 3rd batch which was was fetched by the iterator in the background
7. The iterator starts fetching the 4rd batch in the background
8. etc.

My synchronous implementation:

```
    fun readStructuredLogs(...): Sequence<Payload.JsonPayload> {
        return object : Iterator<LogPayloadType>, AutoCloseable {
            val logging: Logging = options.service
            var currentPage: Page<LogEntry> = logging.listLogEntries(Logging.EntryListOption.filter(buildLogFilter(...))
            var i = 0
            var batch: List<LogEntry> = currentPage.values.toList()
            var isClosed = false

            override fun close() {
                logging.close()
                isClosed = true
            }

            override fun hasNext(): Boolean {
                if (isClosed) 
                    return false
                val hasNext = i < batch.size || currentPage.hasNextPage()
                if (!hasNext) {
                    logging.close()
                }
                return hasNext
            }

            override fun next(): LogPayloadType {
                if (!hasNext()) {
                    throw NoSuchElementException()
                }
                if (i == batch.size - 1 && currentPage.hasNextPage()) {
                    currentPage = currentPage.nextPage
                    batch = currentPage.values.toList()
                    i = 0
                }
                val logEntry = batch[i++]
                return logEntry.getPayload()
            }
        }.asSequence()
    }
```

Ofc I'm open to completely different solutions as long as they can be wrapped in a kotlin's sequence.

**EDIT**

Here is an asynchronous implementation which uses `thread { }`. I couldn't achieve this with coroutines

```
    fun readStructuredLogs(...): Sequence<Payload.JsonPayload> {
        return object : Iterator<LogPayloadType> {
            private var currentPage: Page<LogEntry> = logging.listLogEntries(Logging.EntryListOption.filter(buildLogFilter(...)))
            private var i = 0
            private var batch: List<LogEntry> = currentPage.values.toList()
            private var nextPage: Page<LogEntry>? = null
            private var job: Thread? = null

            override fun hasNext() = i < batch.size || currentPage.hasNextPage()

            override fun next(): LogPayloadType {
                if (!hasNext()) {
                    throw NoSuchElementException()
                }
                if (currentPage.hasNextPage()) {
                    if (nextPage == null && job == null) {
                        job = thread { nextPage = readNextPage(currentPage) }
                    }
                    if (i == batch.size) {
                        job!!.join()
                        currentPage = nextPage!!
                        job = thread { nextPage = readNextPage(currentPage) }
                        batch = currentPage.values.toList()
                        i = 0
                    }
                }
                val logEntry = batch[i++]
                return logEntry.getPayload<Payload<*>>()
            }

            private fun readNextPage(curPage: Page<LogEntry>): Page<LogEntry>? = curPage.nextPage

        }.asSequence()
    }
```

Comment: Of course it will block, but potentially for less time if batches are downloaded beforehead

Comment: I've added an implementation which uses plain old threads

Comment: Am I correct that you can only begin loading a page when the previous page is fully loaded, such that you have the next Page object that you can call `readNextPage` for? So there is no parallelism within this sequence, but the thread that iterates the sequence can be doing work on the current page while the sequence is pre-loading the next page?

Comment: Yes this is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind I can't test any of the following code due to all the classes unknown to me that you're using, so there might be errors.

First of all, your code that uses threads can be simplified quite a bit using the `sequence` builder:

```
// Not sure about how this should behave as you treat it like a blocking function.
// I return null when it's exhausted to simplify while loop.
private fun <T> readNextPageOrNull(page: Page<T>): Page<T>? = 
    if (page.hasNextPage()) page.nextPage!! else null

fun readStructuredLogs(...): Sequence<Payload.JsonPayload> {
    return sequence {
        var jobResult: Page<LogEntry>? = null
        var job = thread {
            jobResult = logging.listLogEntries(Logging.EntryListOption.filter(buildLogFilter(...)))
        }
        while (true) {
            job.join()
            val page = jobResult ?: break
            job = thread { jobResult = readNextPageOrNull(page) }
            yieldAll(page.values.asIterable())
        }
    }
}
```

You can simplify it further and take advantage of thread pools instead of using a bunch of new threads by using `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync {}` instead of `thread {}`:

```
fun readStructuredLogs(...): Sequence<Payload.JsonPayload> {
    return sequence {
        var job = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync {
            logging.listLogEntries(Logging.EntryListOption.filter(buildLogFilter(...)))
        }
        while (true) {
            val page = job.join() ?: break
            job = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync { readNextPageOrNull(page) }
            yieldAll(page.values.asIterable())
        }
    }
}
```

We can convert this to use coroutines, but it is awkward to convert coroutine code to blocking code. You have to use `runBlocking`. This doesn't buy you much, but it will use the coroutine Dispatcher thread pools that you're probably already using if you're using coroutines. Here, `coroutineScope` is whatever scope is appropriate in the current class.

```
fun readStructuredLogs(): Sequence<Payload.JsonPayload> {
    return sequence {
        var job: Deferred<Page<LogEntry>?> = coroutineScope.async(Dispatchers.IO) {
            logging.listLogEntries(Logging.EntryListOption.filter(buildLogFilter(...)))
        }
        while (true) {
            val page = runBlocking { job.await() } ?: break
            job = coroutineScope.async(Dispatchers.IO) { readNextPageOrNull(page) }
            yieldAll(page.values.asIterable())
        }
    }
}
```

If you're already using coroutines, you might consider using a Flow instead of Sequence so it suspends instead of blocking when you're awaiting the next items. There might be a simpler way to do this using Flow operators, but I just did a quick modification of my above sequence code:

```
fun readStructuredLogs(...): Flow<Payload.JsonPayload> {
    return flow {
        var job: Deferred<Page<LogEntry>?> = coroutineScope.async(Dispatchers.IO) {
            logging.listLogEntries(Logging.EntryListOption.filter(buildLogFilter(...)))
        }
        while (true) {
            val page = job.await() ?: break
            job = coroutineScope.async(Dispatchers.IO) { readNextPageOrNull(page) }
            emitAll(page.values.asFlow())
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Possible way to do this with `buffer`:

```
fun readStructuredLogs(...): Flow<Payload.JsonPayload> {
    return flow {
        var page = logging.listLogEntries(Logging.EntryListOption.filter(buildLogFilter(...)))
        while (true) {
            emit(page)
            page = readNextPageOrNull(page) ?: break
        }
    }
        .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
        .buffer(1)
        .flatMapConcat { it.values.asFlow() }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. I will try to use those and see if unit tests pass and give you more feedback. I've totally forgot about yield/emit!

Comment: BTW can I use just `yieldAll(page.values)` instead of `yield + flatMap`?

Comment: Yeah, `yieldAll` is much simpler. I updated it. The `?: break`, `?: continue` and `?: return` pattern is a useful Kotlin idiom that often helps avoid nesting some code in an if or else block.

Comment: I've tested them, two work great, the third one (with Flow) won't compile :( `coroutineScope` is not defined and if changed it to `CoroutineScope.async(Dispatchers.IO)` then I get "Unresolved reference: async" - despite it appears in the auto-complete and is imported. (import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope; import kotlinx.coroutines.async)

Comment: I used `coroutineScope` as an example. Any time you are working with coroutines , you must have some scope from which to start coroutines. It is a key concept of coroutines that you should review before using them. If you are working in a framework like Android, Swing, JavaFX, etc, appropriate coroutine scopes are supplied to you by the associated kotlinx coroutines library. You can also create your own scopes and manage their lifecycles manually yourself using `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)`, `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)`, or `MainScope()`, depending on how you're using it.

Comment: A self-created coroutine scope should be stored in a class property, and it should be cancelled when the associated class has reached it's end of life, so that any currently running coroutines associated with that class will be cancelled. The framework-provided scopes are set up to already do this. For example, on Android the ViewModel class provides `viewModelScope`, and it is automatically cancelled when the ViewModel's life is over (all associated Activities/Fragments destroyed), so its coroutines are cancelled and stop wasting resources on background tasks that won't be used.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I know about coroutine scopes, it's just the first time I've encountered that syntax with explicitly provided receiver. It always was like `someScope { ... async { } }`. I didn't realize you can write `someScope.async { }` . Now it's obvious, thanks again for help!

Comment: Hey, I've been skimming through the Flow API... isn't `.buffer(1)` doing exactly what I was trying to achieve here?

Comment: Yes, I think that fits. But I think you need to go back to emitting one Page at a time, then chain `.buffer(1)`, and then chain `flatMapConcat { it.values.asFlow() }`. Otherwise, you are buffering each individual value from each page, so the preload is potentially delayed before it starts. On the plus side, you won't have to juggle Deferred jobs or worry about specific coroutine scope. I'll add a possible example.